# Issue with case statement and two dates

Tags: mysql, datetime, if-statement, case, statements

In my case statement, I have a date for the previous day with a very specific time.

That specific time, I need for the last six weeks in the case statement. However, due to my second date statement, it does not return the correct values.

How can I fix this?

```
select storeid, orderId, createdDate,
         case 
                    when generatedBy = 0 and (createdDate between '2018-01-09 23:45:00' and '2018-01-09 23:45:59')  
                    then 'Auto' 
                    when generatedBy = 0
                    then 'PDA Trigger'
                    when generatedBy > 0
                    then 'User Trigger'
                    end as 'Triggered By'
from mb_delinotestaging
where createdDate between '2018-01-09' and '2018-01-10'
;
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if all you give is "does not return the correct values".  Give sample input, current output, expected output, ...  Something that help us help you.  Here's a good guide of how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is  your current and expected results?